# Why i need to click twice to let my JButton work?

Tags: java, jframe

I'm building a program that draws `random (User input) rectangles` on a **JPanel**.

**Problem 1:**

> Whenever I type a number in my `JTextfield`,I need to click twice on
>   the JBUtton for  `Rectangles` to show up.

**Problem 2:**

> When i type a new number in the JTextField the number of that don't
>   show the rectangle but it shows the rectangles I typed in previous.

CODE:

```
private void init() {

    final int FRAME_WIDHT = 800;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 1000;
    int input = 3;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDHT, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setTitle("Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    west = new JPanel();
    west.setSize(500, 500);
    west.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    east = new JPanel();
    east.setSize(300, 1000);

    button = new JButton("Add squares");
    field = new JTextField(10);
    button.setSize(100, 50);
    east.add(button);
    east.add(field);
    east.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            JButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }

        public void JButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            int aantalRect = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());

            MyDrawing draw = new MyDrawing(aantalRect);

            west.add(draw);
            draw.revalidate();
            draw.repaint();

        }
    });

    frame.add(west, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);

    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] a) {

    P1027 form = new P1027();

}

}

class MyDrawing extends JPanel {

int input = 0;

public MyDrawing(int i) {

    this.input = i;

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Random r = new Random();

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 1000));

    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {

        int x = r.nextInt(460);
        int y = r.nextInt(960);

        g.drawRect(x, y, 40, 40);

    }

}
```

`Can any one tell me how to fix that?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** You're not be seeing the squares being drawn on your `MyDrawing` `JPanel` the first time because you are calling the `setPreferredSize(...)` method, when you really should be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method as explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229662/4475997). It is also *possible* that they are being drawn off-screen. You set the preferred height of `MyDrawing` to `1000`, which doesn't fit on [*my* laptop's screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qsjZ.png) (The green line is the border of a `MyDrawing`).

To fix Problem 1, override the method and lower the preferred height if necessary:

```
class MyDrawing extends JPanel {

    ... //Constructor

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500); //Changed from 1000 to 500
    }

    ... //paintComponent(...) 
        //If you change 1000 to 500, don't forget to change 960 to 460 too
}
```

**Problem 2:** You're seeing the amount of rectangles you typed into the `JTextField` previously because:

- You are forgetting to remove the previously added `MyDrawing` from `west` before adding the new one.
- You are calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on `draw` when you should be calling it on its parent component, `west`.

To fix problem 2, remove the old `MyDrawing` from `west`, add the new one, then call `revalidate()` and `repaint()`:

```
...
public void JButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    west.removeAll(); //If the old MyDrawing is the only thing 
                      //that has been added to west. Otherwise use
                      //remove(int index) or remove(Component comp)
    west.add(draw);
    west.revalidate();
    west.repaint();
}
...
```

**Other things**:

- You switched the `T` and `H` around in `FRAME_WIDTH`.
- You could put the code in `JButton1ActionPerformed(...)` into the actual `actionPerformed` method.
- Your `JFrame` looks exactly the same with and without the calls to `setSize(...)` on `west`, `east`, and `button` and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229662/4475997) I mentioned earlier suggests not using those methods, so consider removing them.